# inconsistent bean validation initialization of ConstraintValidator defined via ServiceLoader

Tags: spring, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

This question asks for some specifics about more general topic regarding modularization of bean validation I asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485941/how-to-register-custom-constraintmapping-for-validations-defined-in-validation-c).

In question linked above, following [this documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/) and [this post](https://in.relation.to/2017/03/02/adding-custom-constraint-definitions-via-the-java-service-loader/) I split annotation and ConstraintValidator definition into 2 java modules, and linked them together using ServiceLoader as shown in documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_constraint_definitions_via_serviceloader). Works, mostly. But there is one unsolved issue, that *it does not work* for validation defined via XML, which I did according to [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_constraint_definitions_via_serviceloader) again. **What does not work:  The pairing between annotation and ConstraintValidator is not set,** the service loader stuff is not used at all.

To recap: I have working setup using this ServiceLoader approach and it works when validating stuff coming through rest layer. All paired correctly.

BUT! We are getting these DTOs also through kafka. And here we have two different flows. There is some initialization of common ConstraintValidators on startup, and then:

1. if we first get REST message, ServiceLoader stuff is discovered only at this request time, some next initialization is done seemignly, and after that even kafka messages works, meaning pairing for custom validator is available everywhere. (Great!)
2. if kafka message arrives first though(typical), no service loader stuff is consulted and somehow it 'destroys' the configuration in way, that even if later rest request comes it won't work either, saying, that there is no ConstraintValidator for given annotation. The initialization is completed somehow defectively.

validation.xml is as easy as:

```
<validation-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/configuration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/configuration validation-configuration-2.0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

  <constraint-mapping>/META-INF/validation-constraints.xml</constraint-mapping>
</validation-config>
```

notes:

- 2.0 version is because of hibernate-validator 6.2.0 which comes from spring dependency management.
- Why not use annotation and dump this xml stuff altogether? Not mine file, unmodifiable.

If there is some trivial newbie mistake, please advise. Maybe there is some way how to kick in service loader functionality into action in validation.xml file, I'm not aware of and cannot find anywhere.

---

EDITS/suggestions:

A: try to inject validator on startup to make sure it's loaded:

```
@Autowired
private Validator validator;
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void logReady() {
    System.out.println(validator.toString());
}
```

did print initialized validator, did not help though.

Comment: No mention of the stack, so I'm assuming Jakarta EE. Have you tried requesting the validator service in a @Startup bean so as to make sure it gets loaded before any request / Kafka message arrives?

Comment: Thanks for answer, to be honest, I don't know. Please ask, how to find out. We use spring. I don't know what is used inside, but it will be some default. Javax/jakarta is extremely puzzling for me. Loading validator, see edit, did not help. If you can, suggest where to look for service loader code. I've spent several hours debugging and cannot see it yet.

Comment: Ah! Ok, I totally missed that you mentioned Spring. Added `spring` tag to the question

Comment: Well, looking at the code for Hibernate Validator, I found two suspects: [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/8ed05f71e569b2a9d2fefcaf2c14187443f55be8/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/ServiceLoaderBasedConstraintMappingContributor.java), and [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/22620adef18f43f23a1c5d0e1faced68f25af550/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/util/privilegedactions/GetInstancesFromServiceLoader.java). You could try setting breakpoints in each one to check what happens in the two scenarios

Comment: IIUC first call the other, so it's just 1 place, actually. And it's really ugly. During startup, this is called oh-so-many-times, but every time my implementation is found via service loader! Later on they are passed into org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper#putValidatorDescriptors and added into validatorDescriptors map.

Comment: But later on, org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.AbstractConstraintValidatorManagerImpl#findMatchingValidatorDescriptor finds nothing, org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper#getAllValidatorDescriptors returns nothing. So during startup it seems to badly init its structures. Rest calls mysteriously fixes it, other action kills it for good.

Comment: I'd say, there is some initialization mess, and ConstraintHelper is loaded multiple times. It should be helper to track ConstraintValidators (~singleton), but it's created 5 times. So I'd say, the both paths are different and using mismatches non-singleton helpers. No, I don't create any Validator on my own. There is just one autoconfigured bean by spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about this question and I asked this question once more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76290392/how-to-pair-annotation-to-custom-constraintvalidator-in-spring-multimodule-proje/76312566#76312566), but this time I managed to create MWE and behavior was confirmed as Hibernate Validator [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1949).