# How to pair annotation to custom ConstraintValidator in spring multimodule project, when annotation is in different module than implementation

Tags: bean-validation, hibernate-validator

MWE(minimal working example): https://github.com/alfonz19/validator-fail-mwe

TLDR: only xml-based configuration of validation does not work in multimodule project where annotation to `ConstraintViolation` implementation is paired using ServiceLoader. Annotation-based config works always, xml-based does also work when all is put into one module. **Please any hints/idea/suggestions what to debug.**

---

**Update**, famous breakthrough:

if app starts fresh, and first request is served by REST (annotation-based configuration), something missing is probably initialized and all works, including xml-based configuration validation. All good! If app starts fresh, and first request is served via kafka (probably not important) which leads into xml-based configuration logic, something is destroyed(missing initialization finished unsuccessfully) and from that point on nothing works, including rest.

---

If annotation and implementation is in same module, we can trivially bind them together using:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = HasClassTypeValidator.class)
```

or we can(and must in case of multi-module layout) put there:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
```

and define the pairing in ServiceLoader configuration file. So far all good. But I'd like to add validation to auto-generated sources, where I cannot influence them in any way. Easy! You just specify `META-INF/validation.xml`:

```
<validation-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/configuration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/configuration
                    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/configuration/validation-configuration-2.0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

  <constraint-mapping>/META-INF/validation-constraints.xml</constraint-mapping>
</validation-config>
```

and related `validation-constraints.xml` file:

```
<constraint-mappings
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/mapping"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/mapping
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/mapping/validation-mapping-2.0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

  <bean class="Whatever">
    <class ignore-annotations="false"/>

    <getter name="whatever" ignore-annotations="false">
      <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.NotNull"/>
      <constraint annotation="whatever.CustomValidation"/>
    </getter>
    

  </bean>

</constraint-mappings>
```

The only problem is, that it *kinda does not work*. In spring, with it's default autoconfigured Validator via LocalValidatorFactoryBean.

Validation with custom constraints declared via service loader *works* *everywhere* if constraint is specified via annotation. This xml-baxed stuff *also works*, but *ONLY* for built-in constraints, custom one are not found.

If I put breakpoint into `ServiceLoader`, then every call to it WILL discover mine custom validators. If it go through `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` initialization, I eventually got into `org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryConfigurationHelper#registerCustomConstraintValidators`, where I can see my `ConstraintValidator`s discovered as well! But when it comes to validation itself, they are allegedly not declared. **BUT!** If I have annotation, `ConstraintValidators`, xml declarations, and `ServiceLoader` config file in 1 module, it all works! If I take just annotation, `ConstraintValidators` to another module, ONLY the xml-based annotation is broken. Location of `ServiceLoader` config file is irrelevant. No java 9 modules in action, afaik, but it would be weird, that it would affect just xml config based logic.

**QUESTION**:

Hibernate Validator internals are *exceptionally* complex. Can someone advice where to look what could go wrong why `ConstraintValidators` are not available even though they were discovered during `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` initialization?

Comment: Sometimes spring can package jars in a strange manner and might not correctly include resources like `META-INF/services/javax.validation.ConstraintValidator` or a Jakarta version of it. If that's what you've meant by ServiceLoader calls. So you might want to take a look inside the jar file to see if everything is intact....

Comment: @mark_o I appreciate your answer, it's hard to get one with non-trivial questions. Yep, this is the ServiceLoader configuration, and that one is fine, because it works conditionally. The problem is with non-deterministic Validator initialization(see first update). Provably on app startup the initialization is not complete and some lazy-initialized stuff is initialized only on first request. When first request goes through xml-based config, it's is not initialized correctly, even though ServiceLoader is just fine. Need to create minimal working example.

Comment: @mark_o added minimal working example, please check if you can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was confirmed as a Hibernate Validator bug.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1949